# Wordpress - thumbnail images to articles on direct links (without upload img)

Tags: image, wordpress, cdn, posts, article

By the articles of wordpress you can upload images from computer (featured image), but how to set up so that I can specify the full url to image from any other sources? To receive a user posts a picture, not only from my site, but also any other CDN?

English is not my native language, sorry for semantic errors.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this feature? (the *From URL* tab from the Add Media window)
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but unfortunately it's not. I solved this problem by using "custom fields" but it's a bad decision, not native.

Comment: Seems I misunderstood you... But don't know why Custom Fields would be a bad decision... Inside WordPress, they are not foreigners :). - Please post your solution and mark it as the correct answer, so others will benefit from the problem/solution.  Regards.